# How can I get the metadescription of every product?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, collection

I have made a new Controller and inside there a new Action in which I want to be able to get the metadescription of every product. My code snippet is the following:

```
public function metaDescriptionAction()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        var_dump($product->getData());
    }
}
```

But I can't see any information associated with metadescription in the output. What I'm getting is:

```
array (size=52)
'entity_id' => string '20869' (length=5)
 'type_id' => string 'configurable' (length=12)
 'attribute_set_id' => string '4' (length=1)
 'color' => null
 'color_value' => null
 'cost' => null
 'created_at' => string '2016-05-21 07:58:42' (length=19)
 'gift_message_available' => null
 'has_options' => string '1' (length=1)
 'image_label' => null
 'is_recurring' => null
 'links_exist' => null
 'links_purchased_separately' => null
 'links_title' => null
 'msrp' => null
 'msrp_display_actual_price_type' => null
 'msrp_enabled' => null
 'name' => string 'Jean καμπάνα με patchwork' (length=34)
 'news_from_date' => null
 'news_to_date' => null
 'price' => string '99.9000' (length=7)
 'price_type' => null
 'price_view' => null
 'recurring_profile' => null
 'required_options' => string '1' (length=1)
 'shipment_type' => null
 'short_description' => string 'Jean καμπάνα με patchwork' (length=34)
 'sku' => string '9905202' (length=7)
 'sku_type' => null
 'small_image' => null
 'small_image_label' => null
 'special_from_date' => null
 'special_price' => string '30.0000' (length=7)
 'special_to_date' => null
 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
 'tax_class_id' => string '2' (length=1)
 'thumbnail' => null
 'thumbnail_label' => null
 'updated_at' => string '2017-03-27 10:58:54' (length=19)
 'url_key' => string 'jean-kampana-me-patchwork' (length=25)
 'url_path' => string 'jean-kampana-me-patchwork.html' (length=30)
 'visibility' => string '4' (length=1)
 'weight' => null
 'weight_type' => null
 'size' => string '435' (length=3)
 'size_value' => string 'XL-14' (length=5)
 'barcode' => string '9905202' (length=7)
 'cvg_smartprice' => null
 'season' => string '20' (length=2)
 'season_value' => string 'ΧΕΙΜΩΝΑΣ ' (length=17)
 'is_salable' => string '0' (length=1)
 'stock_item' => 
   object(Varien_Object)[61]
     protected '_data' => 
      array (size=1)
        'is_in_stock' => string '0' (length=1)
    protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean false
  protected '_origData' => null
  protected '_idFieldName' => null
  protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
  protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know it helps you.

Comment: If you have found an own soultion or an answer here, please post it or accept one to close this. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that I had to go to **Product->Catalog->General** and then enable the Visible on catalog option. The the controller is the following:

```
public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $csv = '';
    $_columns = array(
        "Id",
        "Product Name/H1",
        "Meta description",
        "Meta Title",
        "Url"
        );
    $data = array();

    foreach ($_columns as $column) {
        $data[] = '"'.$column.'"';
    }
    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $loadProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getProductId());

        $data = array();
        $data[] = $product->getId();
        $data[] = $product->getName();
        $data[] = $product->getMetaDescription();
        $data[] = $product->getMetaTitle();
        $data[] = 'mysite/'.$product->getUrlKey();

        $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
    }

    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file.csv', $csv, 'text/csv');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('meta_title','meta_description'));

foreach ($collection as $product) { 
    print_r($product->getData()); 
}
```

output

> Array ( [entity_id] => 231 [entity_type_id] => 4 [attribute_set_id] => 13 [type_id] => simple [sku] => msj000 [has_options] => 0 [required_options] => 0 [created_at] => 2013-03-05 10:48:12 [updated_at] => 2017-07-07 11:35:03 [meta_title] => fgdg [meta_description] => dfgfdgf [is_salable] => 1 [stock_item] => Varien_Object Object ( [_data:protected] => Array ( [is_in_stock] => 1 ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => [_origData:protected] => [_idFieldName:protected] => [_isDeleted:protected] => [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: I'm not getting the [meta-description]   .... have I done something wrong in the admin ?

Comment: @Stefanos it is `[meta_description]` and do the reindexing  and make sure updated the cache or disabled even better

Comment: Cleared the cache twice, then reindexed... still, no [meta_description]

Comment: @Stefanos product detail page showing the description?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Stefanos i mean product view page showing the meta_description and title.

Answer (score 0):

It should be when you load the product:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());  

if($_product){
    $title = $_product->getMetaTitle();
    $keyword = $_product->getMetaKeyword();
    $description = $_product->getMetaDescription();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but it takes almost 10 minutes to finish loading.... and I only get two values... I'm wandering if it's valid

Comment: Yes it's because every product is loaded completely, including all the attributes and other data. This could take quite long when you have a large collection, though it would certainly not require 10 minutes... I think @Qaisar Satti's answer is a better solution, in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in manually:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('meta_keyword');

foreach ($collection as $product) {         
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

Comment: This return an array but there is no meta_description anywhere... have I done something wrong anywhere in the back end?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getMetaKeyword(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getMetaDescription(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the flat catalog flag enabled.
This means that the collection of products is retrieved from the flat tables. This means that if you want a certain attribute it needs to be in that table.
Go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes, look for the `meta_description` attribute, edit it and set the flag "Used in product listing" to "Yes".
Then rebuild your indexes.
After that your code should work.

Comment: I can't see any neta_description attribute there... that's weird cause in the meta section I can see it

Comment: It should be there, it's a Magento core attribute. Maybe you have a filter applied?